# Convert image into mp4 that zooms in to precise point in image

Tags: images, video, zoom

I have an image. From this image, I need to create an mp4 that zooms in to a precise square within the image (about 1/64th the original size). How would I go about creating this file? The most obvious way seems to be to create a series of pictures which progressively zoom, and to then convert those images to video. However, I can't figure out how to create the individual images such that they eventually end on the desired square within the image. Alternatively, I tried Windows Movie Maker but could not specify the final space on which I need the video to stop, nor the rate at which the video should progress.

Comment: Have you explored Photoshop's Timeline animations?

Comment: Iwould use a real animation sofware, after effects or blender for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a layer change size in an animation in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25605/how-to-make-a-layer-change-size-in-an-animation-in-photoshop). It should be possible t do this in CS 6 and beyond just as easily as in AE See the last answer.

Comment: Try animating this in reverse. Start on your target and zoom out.

Comment: I disagree that there are "too many possible answers"... A MP4 file is a video file and should be produced with a NLE, most of them work the same way...

Answer (score 2):

I will explain how to do this in After Effects, but many other NLE such as Premiere Pro or Final Cut Pro X offer the same features, only slightly differently presented:

1. Open After Effects (or your NLE editor)
2. Import the image into it
3. Make it the exact duration that you want your shot to be
4. Create keyframes for "position" and "scale" on this layer at the beginning of the timeline with your image zoomed out
5. Go to the last frame of the animation, and zoom and position it the way you want the zoom to be
6. Export to MP4

I just did it to try out this solution; it took me 5 minutes to do this in AE and the result was a professional 1080p MP4 file at 59 pictures per second, very smooth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are easier ways of doing this such a AE or 3ds max etc but it is completely possible in photoshop. As you say, this will be a series of the same image expanding to achieve your result. You will need the one image and then x amount of animation frames on the timeline. In the fi[image]rst frame you will set the image so it zoomed out as much as you want. then each frame you will need to duplicate the image and increase the size - thus resulting in the zoom effect, this can be very time consuming **BUT** possible. see attached, I mocked up a gif to illustrate this.

Hope this helps,
Mark

Comment: As you've said, this seems very time-taking and the resulting movement is extremely choppy.

Comment: hey, didn't say this was the best idea, just said it was possible. that gif took about 5mins to make so will obv be choppy. If you have after effects just use that and set a camera path to fly to it or 3ds max.

Comment: but the user needs a MP4 file, could your solution produce one?

Comment: sure, same process, I initially rendered it as an MP4 to upload here to show you, but was more than the 2mb upload limit here.

Comment: Ok. Why would you recommend using a photo retouching tool to produce a video file rather than a video editor, though?